# Explode PHP String

Tags: php, explode

I need some help, is it possible to explode like this?
I have a string `45-test-sample`, is it possible to have

```
[0]=>string == "45"
[1]=>string == "test-sample"
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want to extract? Do you just want to be able to read the number separately? What sort of template string are you working with? is it always in the same format of `45-test-sample`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
print_r(explode('-', $string, 2));    // take some help from the limit parameter
```

According to the PHP manual for **[explode][1]**

> If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 45
    [1] => test-sample
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Explode has a limit parameter.

```
$array = explode('-', $text, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$str = "45-test-sample";
$arr = explode('-', $str, 2);
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 45
    [1] => test-sample
)
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/178454)**

Answer (score 0):

Try with exact output using list.

```
<?php
  $str = "45-test-sample";
  list($a,$b) = explode('-', $str, 2);
  $arr=Array();
  $arr=['0'=>"String == ".$a,'1'=>"String == ".$b];
  print_r($arr);
```

?>

Output:

```
Array
(
   [0] => String == 45
   [1] => String == test-sample
)
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/1109232)